# Memory pressure due to download and saving of images

Tags: ios, iphone, memory-leaks, out-of-memory, memory-pressure

Fortunately I know where my memory pressure issue is coming from, and I have tried a number of techniques such as wrapping a block in an @autorelease block and setting objects to nil but still no success.

Sorry for dumping too much code here, I tried to cut it down to the essentials. Here is the code for downloading and saving images:

```
NSMuttableArray *photosDownOps = [NSMuttableArray array];
NSURL *URL = [...];
NSURLRequest *request = [...];
AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
op.responseSerializer = [AFImageResponseSerializer serializer];

[op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {    
    dispatch_queue_t amBgSyncQueue = dispatch_queue_create("writetoFileThread", NULL);
    dispatch_async(amBgSyncQueue, ^{
        [self savePhotoToFile:(UIImage *)responseObject usingFileName:photo.id];
    });    
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    if ([error code] !=  NSURLErrorCancelled)
        NSLog(@"Error occured downloading photos: %@", error);
}];
[photosDownOps addObject:op];

NSArray *photosDownloadOperations = [AFURLConnectionOperation batchOfRequestOperations:photosDownloadOperatons 
                                                                         progressBlock:^(NSUInteger nof, NSUInteger tno) {        
} completionBlock:^(NSArray *operations) {
    NSLog(@"all photo downloads completed");
}];

[self.photosDownloadQueue addOperations:photosDownloadOperations waitUntilFinished:NO];

+ (void) savePhotoToFile:(UIImage *)imageToSave usingFileName:(NSNumber *)photoID{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSData * binaryImageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageToSave, 0.6);
        NSString *filePath = [Utilities fullPathForPhoto:photoID];
        [binaryImageData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
        binaryImageData = nil;
        imageToSave = nil;
    }
}
```

This situation though only happens with iPhone 4s devices that I have tested on, it does not happen on iPhone 5 models.

Comment: Have you measured your code's memory usage with Instruments? That will tell you where the allocations are coming from, grouped by object type and with allocation histories for each instance. You first will need to determine which objects are causing all of the memory pressure, then track down those objects to their origins and through all of their uses to know how to proceed.

Comment: What is the resolution of the images you are fetching, and what is the maximum resolution they need to be for display? Do you have any opportunity to scale down the images so you are working with less data overall? How many images are you typically handling in an average app session?

Comment: As I can see the whole image is downloaded in cache first then it is returned to you in success block. This may be a reason of memory spike if image size is considerably large. You should write your own operation which makes request inside, in didReceiveData method of NSUrlConnectionDelegate you receive response data in chunks, use NSOutputStream to write that data to desired file location. I think this would solve your problem.

Comment: @bneely main culprits to be VM: CG rasta data and VM: ImageIO_Data each with overall bytes of 130MB each and the whole app ate an overallbytes of 1.2GB. I'm pulling down a total of 105 images each at 480x640 resolution and size < 90kB each.

Comment: Can you write the images to disk before treating them as UIImages? Are the images displayed/used right away after they are fetched? You could handle them as opaque NSData and write them to disk that way. Then you would avoid unnecessary UIImage caching. When you need a given image, load it from disk and then call UIImageJPEGRepresentation(). In other words, defer the UIImage work until the last possible moment.

Comment: before the completion block is called, AFNetworking would have already serialized the response into a UIImage, I've dumped AFNetworking for performing the downloads, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this by extending NSOperation and within the main block immediately after I receive the data I write it out to file:

```
- (void)main{
    @autoreleasepool {
        //...
        NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:imageUrl];        
        if (imageData) {
            NSError *error = nil;
            [imageData writeToFile:imageSavePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

This NSOperation object was then added a NSOperationQueue I already had.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create your own class to download image using NSUrlConnection and in the delegate method append that data to your file just see the below code

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {

NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:aPath]; 
[fileHandle seekToEndOfFile]; 
[fileHandle writeData:data]; 
[fileHandle closeFile];

}
```

This will help you in memory management as all the data which is download is not need to cache .

Comment: I get the idea but it didn't work for me, maybe I may have not implemented it right.